# Program crashes due to undefined behavior

Tags: c++

So I'm writing a program that creates a library for a collection of CDs and displays them.  My program compiles but crashes whenever I write an array of pointers to songs from a file into structs contained within an array shown here:

```
//Get song array
        for (int a = 0; a < num_songs; a++)
            {

            getline (infile, line);
            sub = line.c_str();
            word = createString(sub);


            length = substr(word, -1, 5);
            title = substr(word, 5, strlen(sub));
            cd->song_array[a] = createSong(title,length);
            destroyString(word);

            }
```

I think it's due to undefined behavior, here's the .cpp file that this is happening in.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include "CDs.h"
#include "CD.h"
#include  <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

//Creates a collection of CDs
CDs* createCDs(const char* file_name)
{
//Declare variables and allocate memory
int max_cds = 50;
CDs* collection = new CDs;
collection->max_cds = max_cds;
CD** cd_array = new CD*[max_cds];

int num;
int sentinel = 0;
String* word;
string line;
CD* cd;
const char* sub;
String* length;
String* title;

//Open .txt file
ifstream infile;
infile.open(file_name);



if (infile.is_open())
    {
    while (infile.good())
        {   

        for (int i = 0; i < max_cds; i++)
            {

            //Get the artist from .txt file
            cd = cd_array[i];
            getline (infile, line);
            sub = line.c_str();
            word = createString(sub);  //Create string from infile line
            cd->artist = word;
            destroyString(word);


            //Get the Title of the album from file
            getline (infile, line);
            sub = line.c_str();
            word = createString(sub);
            cd->title = word;
            destroyString(word);

            //Get the Year of the album from file
            infile >> num;
            cd->year = num;

            //Get the Rating
            infile >> num;
            cd->rating = num;

            //Get number of tracks
            int num_songs;
            infile >> cd->num_tracks;

            //Get song array
            for (int a = 0; a < num_songs; a++)
                {

                getline (infile, line);
                sub = line.c_str();
                word = createString(sub);


                cout << "SHIT" << endl;
                length = substr(word, -1, 5);
                title = substr(word, 5, strlen(sub));
                cd->song_array[a] = createSong(title,length);
                destroyString(word);

                }

            cd_array[i] = cd;   
            sentinel++;


            }

        }
    }
else
    {
    cout << "file did not open";
    }

collection->cd_array = cd_array;
collection->num_cds = sentinel;
collection->max_cds = max_cds;
return collection;
}
```

I have no idea what to do to make this run, If someone could help that  would be amazing.

edit - I didn't give the .cpp that is included and has some of the functions used

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "String.h"
using namespace std;

//Function that creates a string
String* createString(const char* char_array)
{
//Allocate memory for a pointer to String struct
//String* string;
String* string = new String;

//Write the char_array to String struct
int length = strlen(char_array);

char array[30];
for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
    array[i] = char_array[i];
    string->array[i] = array[i];
    }
return string;
}
//Function that displays the string
void displayString(String* str)
{
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str->array); i++)
    {
    cout << str->array[i];
    }
cout << endl;
}

//Function that destroys the string
void destroyString(String* str)
{
delete str;
str = NULL;
}

int find(String* str, char delimiter, int start)
{
for (int i = start; i <= strlen(str->array); i++)
    {
    if (str->array[i] == delimiter) 
        {
        return i;
        }
    }
cout << "No occurences of delimiter were found" << endl;
return -1;
}

String* substr(String* str, int start, int end)
{
String* new_str = new String;
int count = 0;
for (int i = start + 1; i < end - 1; i++)
    {
    new_str->array[count] = str->array[i];
    count++;
    }

return new_str;
}

void compare(String* str1, String* str2)
{
if (str1->array < str2->array)
    {
    cout << str1->array << " is less than " << str2->array << endl;
    }
if (str1 > str2)
    {
    cout << str2->array <<" is less than " << str1->array << endl;
    }
if (str1 == str2)
    {
    cout << "The strings are equal" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered debugging it?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do that. I'm really new to programming, how would I go about that, I use notepad++ so there's no built in debugger.

Comment: You should start by refactoring your code: replace `CD** cd_array` with `std::vector<CD>`, `String` with `std::string` and don't use pointers to `String`\`std::string` when that's not necessary.

Comment: @user3330884 notepad++? seriously? there are free IDEs on all platforms.

Comment: My tip is not to use uninitialized variables. You write `int num_songs; /* something */;` and then you use `num_songs`. This will crash unless you overloaded the `>>` operator to magically change that variable

Comment: I fixed the undefined variables that I found, It still crashes. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: What is `createString` and `substr` ?

Comment: `cd = cd_array[i];` causes undefined behaviour because `cd_array[i]` is uninitialized

Comment: those are functions that are in another .cpp include into this one, I'll edit my original post so you can see them.

Answer (score 0):

You never allocate memory for the effective CD. You just allocate an array of pointers to CDs (cd_array). This means you have an array of pointers, pointing to unkown memory locations.

The best way to ensure no such bad access is possible, is to not dynamically allocate memory. Just use CD cd_array[max_cds] and work with that. (Use call by reference, if you need to pass this to a function.)

Comment: He would also have to make `max_cds` const

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines:

```
    //Get the artist from .txt file 
           cd_array[i] = new CD; 
           cd = cd_array[i];
           .....
```

You should de-allocate the memory once finished using them

```
for(...)
 delete cd_array[i];

delete []cd_array;
```

Comment: And memory leaks follow.

Comment: @nwp, memory will be leaked if allocated objects are not deleted. but that is not concern of OP's question, though it is a good idea to give him a hint.

Comment: Well I am one of the "`new` and `delete` are evil"-faction and would advice to use `vector`, `array` or `unique_ptr`. By the way something doesn't look right in your first code. Is `cd` a type or a variable?

Comment: @nwp, I believe everyone should play around the nasty things like memory management at first while learning basics, instead of jumping for STL. There is a typo in my code, thanks for pointing out.